# What information about me do online stores get via my credit card?

Tags: credit-card, user-tracking, payment-gateway

I found the exact same question about physical stores: 
[What information about me do stores get via my credit card?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207241/what-information-about-me-do-stores-get-via-my-credit-card?newreg=6bba33a648f74c8f9524504bc29cf40a)

Though I am interested in online stores! Are there big difference between PHYSICAL and DIGITAL store transactions and the processes involved?

What information do merchants get about me (or my credit card) from this transaction? For example I know about BIN and AVS what else can they find out? What other APIs do they talk to,...

This is probably very specific for different countries are there any standards though, if not I am the most interested about Europe transactions cross crountries (e.g. France->UK, UK->Hungary,...) in this case. If you only know about US specific feel free to post it as well though maybe we can collect a good collection of info on this!

Thanks a lot for your info!

Comment: It might be better to ask if there is a difference between "physical stores" and "online stores" before assuming there is a difference and asking for the different information. Why do you think there would be a difference?

Comment: Maybe that would have been a better question! I am a noob when it comes to this topic, can you recommend any sources to get me started with payment gateways and how online payments or even physical payments work. It can go into depth but keep in mind I am new to this! Hope you got some, thanks!

Comment: There _is_ definitely a difference between what information the store gets depending on whether the card is physically present or not.  But all the data about the cardholder is effectively the same.  The only real difference with that is whether it comes from the track/chip data, or whether the customer is prompted to enter it themselves.