# What informations can a website store about my credit card?

Tags: credit-card

I read on [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/207241/what-information-about-me-do-stores-get-via-my-credit-card) topic that, after performing a payment, websites can store and read:

- Your PAN
- Your zip code / cardholder name / any information you input on a website that has fillable informations within the website itself (like Tinder)

Is it still true in 2023?
Is it legal for them to store and read these informations for purposes like fraud detection and such?

Comment: That question is only 4 years old. Nothing has changed. And we can't comment on legalities here. Law.stackexchange.com handles that.